# multi producer, single consumer queue with char[]

Tags: c++, c++11, queue, critical-section, circular-buffer

My project's code base current contains a multi-producer, single consumer data writer. It uses 2 circular buffers and a couple of CRITICALSECTION locks to write variably sized streams of data passed in as char* with a byte count. It takes data from dozens+ of threads writing char* and writes them to a binary file.

I'm looking to improve this design, but it seems that all the implementations that are written on the net involve simple primitive types as opposed to writing char arrays. Can anyone suggest links for me to research, as my google-fu is pretty weak?

My test implementation is essentially:

```
Record(char* data, uint32_t byte_count)
{
    c_section.Lock();  //CCriticalSection, std::mutex, whatever
    recording_buffer.write(data, byte_count);  //in house circular buff
    c_section.Unlock();
}
FileThread()
{
    while(run_thread)
    {
        if(recording_buffer.size() > 0)
        {
            c_section.Lock();
            //read the entire size of the filled bytes of the buffer
            //multiple entries are written to the file at once.
            write_to_file(recording_buffer.read(recording_buffer.size()), recording_buffer.size();
            c_section.Unlock();
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
    }
}
```

Comment: _simple primitive types as opposed to writing char arrays_ isn't a char array a simple primitive type?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a semantic thing, but i would say that a char is a primitive type, but a char[] is not. It's certainly possible that i'm wrong though. My point is that we have to write the entirety of the char[] into the queue not a char at a time.

Comment: Instead of polling, the consumer thread(s) could use a semaphore as a signal to consume.